# beforeunload event on Single Page Application (SPA) Website using Google Tag Manager (GTM)

Tags: google-analytics, react-router, single-page-application, google-tag-manager, onbeforeunload

I would like to track *beforeunload* event on SPA website, as I want to send data via GTM to datalayer. I want to track video watch time (HTML5 player) and send the data right before a user leaves the current page either to another one on the same website or completely different.

Is there a way to have this done via GTM custom HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a way to capture the video time in a variable, you can send that information to Google Analytics using an event listener for the beforeunload event. I’m doing that on one of my webpages to get an idea of how long users have the page open.

Here’s the code I’m using:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=GA_MEASUREMENT_ID"></script>
<script>
    // Disable tracking if the opt-out cookie exists
    if (document.cookie.indexOf("ga-disable-GA_MEASUREMENT_ID=true") > -1) {
        window["ga-disable-GA_MEASUREMENT_ID"] = true;
    }

    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag("js", new Date());
    gtag("config", "GA_MEASUREMENT_ID", { "anonymize_ip": true, "cookie_flags": "SameSite=None;Secure" });
</script>

<script> 
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
        gtag('event', 'Time_Spent', {
            'event_category': 'Time_on_page',
            'event_label': e.timeStamp.toString,
            'value': 1,
            'transport_type': 'beacon'
        });

        delete e.returnValue;
    });
</script>
```

The first section is in the head and the second section is at the end of the body.

I put the event.timeStamp value in the event_label; you could put your video time, formatted however you like into that field as well.

I’m not sure I need the optional value field, but I have it.

The transport_type beacon tells Google to transmit the data asynchronously when the User Agent has an opportunity to do so, without delaying unload or the next navigation.

To see how long people have been spending with my page open, I go to:

Google Analytics -> Behavior -> Events -> Overview

I click on the event category (Time_on_page in my case), and then click on Event Label to get a listing of all of the values.